# Solaris 10 non-global zone's IP addresses not visible to the global zone

Tags: solaris, solaris-10

I have a Solaris 10 box that I use for testing.  I configured some non-global zones on it in the following manner:

```
mkdir -p /zones/wks
chmod 700 /zones/wks
zonecfg -z wks
create
set autoboot=true
set type=ufs
end
add net
set address=192.128.1.171
set physical=hme0
end
verify
commit
exit
```

and

```
mkdir -p /zones/cdg_a
chmod 700 /zones/cdg_a
zonecfg -z cdg_a
create
set autoboot=true
set type=ufs
end
add net
set address=192.128.1.172
set physical=hme0
end
verify
commit
exit
```

The global zone is 192.168.1.170.  When I try to ping 171 or 172, it's not alive!  From the global, I ran ifconfig -a and got this:

```
lo0:1
zone wks
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000

lo0:2
zone cdg_a
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000
```

What the French Toast?!  I absolutely speficied IPs 171 and 172 in the zonecfg.  But they appear as local loopbacks from the global?

Also, I don't understand the netmask returned in hex either?  I'm not running IPv6 or anything.

I usually like to ask questions where I can illustrate research and R-ingTFM prior to posting but I'm really lost on this.

This is a standalone server.  I'm using, or would like to use, non-global zones to help me make better use of resources and simulate multiple instances of the same host for the testing I have to do.  Oracle's docs say I need a default route in my zonecfg but that is really confusing to me as this is a standalone box.

How do I have to change the configuration of the non-globals so I can ping from zone to zone by address?

Comment: What version of Solaris 10?

Comment: Are the zones running?  What's the output of `zoneadm list -v`?  (that may not be exactly correct - it's been a few years for me...)

Comment: Thanks for the replies @fpmurphy and Andrew Henle  

The version is 10 1/13 s10x_u11wos_24a X86  

The output of zoneadm list is:  
    ID  NAME           Status         PATH                   BRAND        IP  
     0  global         running        /                      native       shared  
     1  cdg_a          running        /zones/cdg_a           native       shared  
     2  wks            running        /zones/wks             native       shared

Comment: Sorry for the formatting of the last reply... the Markdown editing is NOT working!  I've tried 2 spaces for a break and 4 spaces for an indent and NOTHING is formatting correctly to make that last reply readable.

Comment: @MGoBlue93 Edit the question itself and add the output.  You can format better there.

Comment: @Andrew Henle, any thoughts/suggestions why I still cannot ping?

Comment: The only thing I see offhand is you don't set a default router with the defrouter command.  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19044-01/sol.containers/817-1592/z.conf.start-29/index.html  I'm also wondering if `hme0` needs to be plumbed from the global zone.